# no suitable driver found exception in servlet call

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, servlets

I try to do this in my dao class

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDB", "postgres", "123456");
```

and there is a "no suitable driver found exception in servlet call" exception.

When I try it in my other test project it works well, but here I've got this error. I think that the problem is that tomcat server (where I deploy this app) cant find lib postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4. 
But my build file copies it to WEB-INF/lib directory after deploying.

Also I tried to copy it into tomcat/lib but it didnt work.

Can you help me?

Comment: i suggest you to follow this link:http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/

Comment: load the driver before it using class.forName method.

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta: that is no longer necessary since Java 6 (and a JDBC 4 compliant driver)

Comment: Thanks i wasn't aware.

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta class.forName actually resolved the problem.

Comment: In general, you should use DataSources in web applications, instead of loading DriverManager and creating connections by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You should include postgres driver like this before getting connection from DriverManager

`Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");`

for postgres sql

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `postgresql` driver to your classpath.

[driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html)